# Navigation bar wraps around in certain browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

You can view a demo of the page I'm working on here:  http://www.privateservercloud.com

When I open this page in FireFox, it displays the top navigation bar correctly.  However, when viewing it in Chrome or Internet Explorer, the navigation bar is wrapping around.

What can be done to fix this so it works in all browsers the same way?  Is there a way I can restrict it so that it doesn't wrap around and keep everything on the same line?

Here's a copy of the code for the navigation bar:

```
<div class="navbar whmcscontainer" style="margin-top:14px;">
  <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
      <div class="menu" style="text-align: center;">
<ul style="padding: 0; white-space:nowrap;" id="treemenu1">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li style="white-space:nowrap;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/panel">SEO Dashboard</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li style="white-space:nowrap;"><a href="#">Manage Campaigns</a>
        <ul style="margin-left: 1px; width: 179px;">
            <li style="width:175px;margin-top:-7px;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/panel/urls"><span class="hoverer" style="width:180px; margin-left:5px;">Keywords & Websites</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:175px;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/panel/groups"><span class="hoverer" style="width:180px; margin-left:5px;">Add / Remove Groups</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:175px;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/panel/settings/predefined-filters"><span class="hoverer" style="width:180px; margin-left:5px;">Setup Custom Filters</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:175px;border-bottom:0;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/panel/tags"><span class="hoverer" style="width:180px; margin-left:5px;">Create Special Tags</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li style="white-space:nowrap;"><a href="#">Reporting System</a>
        <ul style="margin-left:0;width:169px;">
            <li style="width:164px;margin-top:-7px;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/panel/reports/overview"><span class="hoverer" style="width:169px; margin-left:5px;">The Overview Report</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:164px;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/panel/reports/daily"><span class="hoverer" style="width:169px; margin-left:5px;">My Daily Breakdown</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:164px;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/panel/reports/automated"><span class="hoverer" style="width:169px; margin-left:5px;">Automated Reports</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:164px;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/panel/reports/notification"><span class="hoverer" style="width:169px; margin-left:5px;">Custom Notifications</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:164px;border-bottom:0;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/panel/reports/share"><span class="hoverer" style="width:169px; margin-left:5px;">Shared Report Links</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li style="white-space:nowrap;"><a href="#">General Settings</a>
        <ul style="margin-left:1px;width:158px;">
            <li style="width:154px;margin-top:-7px;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/panel/settings"><span class="hoverer" style="width:159px; margin-left:5px;padding:8px 0 6px 4px;">Rank Tracker Settings</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:154px;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/panel/reports/custom"><span class="hoverer" style="width:159px; margin-left:5px;">Customize Templates</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:154px;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/panel/settings/predefined-filters/"><span class="hoverer" style="width:159px; margin-left:5px;">My Predefined Filters</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:154px;border-bottom:0;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/panel/settings/cloud-storage/"><span class="hoverer" style="width:159px; margin-left:5px;">Setup Cloud Storage</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li style="white-space:nowrap;"><a href="#">Support Center</a>
        <ul style="margin-left:0;width:152px;">
            <li style="width:147px;margin-top:-7px;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/members/contact.php"><span class="hoverer" style="width:152px; margin-left:5px;">Create New Ticket</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:147px;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/members/supporttickets.php"><span class="hoverer" style="width:152px; margin-left:5px;">My Existing Tickets</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:147px;border-bottom:0;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/members/knowledgebase"><span class="hoverer" style="width:152px; margin-left:5px;">Knowledge Base</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li style="white-space:nowrap;"><a href="#" style="border-right:0;">Account Details</a>
        <ul style="margin-left:0;width:157px;">
            <li style="width:147px;margin-top:-7px;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/members/clientarea.php"><span class="hoverer" style="width:156px; margin-left:5px;">Billing Overview</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:147px;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/members/upgrade.php?type=package&amp;id=2"><span class="hoverer" style="width:156px; margin-left:5px;">Upgrade/Downgrade</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:147px;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/members/affiliates.php"><span class="hoverer" style="width:156px; margin-left:5px;">Affiliate Dashboard</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:147px;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/members/clientarea.php?action=details"><span class="hoverer" style="width:156px; margin-left:5px;">Edit Account Details</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:147px;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/members/clientarea.php?action=invoices"><span class="hoverer" style="width:156px; margin-left:5px;">Search My Invoices</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:147px;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/members/clientarea.php?action=changepw"><span class="hoverer" style="width:156px; margin-left:5px;">Change Password</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:147px;border-bottom:0;border-top:0;"><a href="http://privateservercloud.com/members/logout.php"><span class="hoverer" style="width:156px; margin-left:5px;">Account Logout</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help that anyone can provide will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wraps for me in Firefox too.

Changing the horizontal padding from 25px to 23px fixes it in all three browsers.

```
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    ...
    padding: 15px 23px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I was going to do that, but is there any way to work around having the extra space on the right side?  When I change it to 23px, there's extra space to the right of "Account Details"...